How to use value="{{ old('value', default_value) }}" when appending code from JavaScript to Blade on Laravel 10
I'm working on the project which I have to make my users to be able to add and remove items; in this case is the reward information. I'm developing this on Laravel 10 and I've tried so many attempts to get the old values from the controller when the validation is failed by the rules I declared.
In my JavaScript, I have addMoreItem() function and removeItem() function. In addMoreItem() function, I can used value="{{ old('reward_name') }}". After the failure, I have to check for the old value(s) by using @json('reward') which contains the array of reward data like this :
{"1":
    {
        "reward_award_status":"1",
        "reward_type_id":"1",
        "reward_owner_name":"International Kid Scientist Programme",
        "reward_owner_description":"Example of Description",
        "reward_date":"2024-10-04",
        "reward_name":"International Kid Scientist",
        "reward_education_level_id":"1",
        "reward_academic_year":"2024",
        "reward_academic_semester":"1",
        "reward_prize_amount":null
    },
"2":
    {
        "reward_award_status":"1",
        "reward_type_id":"3",
        "reward_owner_name":"National Kid Scientist Programme",
        "reward_owner_description":"Example of Description",
        "reward_date":"2024-10-04",
        "reward_name":"National Kid Scientist",
        "reward_education_level_id":"1",
        "reward_academic_year":"2024",
        "reward_academic_semester":"1",
        "reward_prize_amount":null
    },
}

After I got the old values as above, I will work in JavaScript like this :
var reward_items = @json(old('reward_total_items', 0));
if(reward_items > 0){
    const reward_details = @json(old('reward'));
    Object.entries(reward_details).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        $('#reward_details').append(
            '<div id="reward-' + key + '" class="card border-dark mt-3 mb-3' + '">' +
                        '<div class="card-header bg-warning">' +
                            '<div class="row align-items-center">' +
                                '<div class="col d-flex justify-content-start">' +
                                    '<strong>Reward Information</strong>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">' +
                                    '<a class="btn btn-clear text-center" onclick="removeReward(\'reward-' + key + '\');">' +
                                        '<i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>' +
                                        '<strong>Remove This Item</strong>' +
                                    '</a>' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +

                        '<input type="text" id="reward_' + key + '_reward_award_status" name="reward[' + key + '][reward_award_status]" class="form-control" value="{{ old("reward.' + key + '.reward_award_status", ' + value.reward_award_status + ') }}" style="display: none;"/>' + 

                        '<div class="card-body">' +
                            '<div class="row row-cols-1">' +
                                '<div class="col mt-1 mb-1">' +
                                    '<label for="reward_' + key + '_reward_type_id" class="form-label">' +
                                        '<strong>Reward Type <span style="color: red;">*</span> : </strong>' +
                                    '</label>' +
                                    '<select id="reward_' + key + '_reward_type_id" name="reward[' + key + '][reward_type_id]" class="form-select form-control search-on-selection ' +
                                        '@error("reward.' + key + '.reward_type_id") is-invalid @enderror" style="width: 100%;">' +
                                        '<option value="" selected disabled>Please Type</option>' +
                                        reward_type_list.map(reward_type => {
                                            return '<option value="' + reward_type.id + '" ' +
                                                (value.reward_type_id == reward_type.id ? 'selected' : '') + 
                                                ' data-is-get-reward="' + reward_type.is_get_reward + '">' +
                                                reward_type.name + '</option>';
                                        }).join('') + 
                                    '</select>' +
                                    '@error("reward.' + key + '.reward_type_id")' +
                                        '<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">' +
                                            '<strong>{{ $message }}</strong>' +
                                        '</span>' +
                                    '@enderror' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +

                            '<div id="reward_' + key + '_reward_details" name="reward_' + key + '_reward_details" class="@if(' + value.reward_award_status + ' == "1")' + ' d-block @endif">' +
                                '<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-1 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-2">' +
                                    '<div class="col mt-1 mb-1">' +
                                        '<label for="reward_' + key + '_reward_owner_name" class="form-label">' +
                                            '<strong>Reward Owner Name <span style="color: red;">*</span> : </strong>' +
                                        '</label>' +
                                        '<input type="text" id="reward_' + key + '_reward_owner_name" name="reward[' + key + '][reward_owner_name]" class="form-control ' +
                                            '@error("reward.' + key + '.reward_owner_name") is-invalid @enderror" ' +
                                            'placeholder="Please Type Reward Owner Name" ' +
                                            'value="{{ old(\'reward.' + key + '.reward_owner_name\', ) }}"' +
                                            'onkeyup="typeOnlyEN(\'reward_' + key + '_reward_owner_name\');" ' +
                                            'onkeydown="typeOnlyEN(\'reward_' + key + '_reward_owner_name\');"/>' +
                                        '<span class="invalid-feedback type_alert_reward_reward_owner_name" role="alert" style="display: none;">' +
                                            '<strong>Please specify in English</strong>' +
                                        '</span>' +
                                        '@error("reward.' + key + 'reward.reward_owner_name")' +
                                            '<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">' +
                                                '<strong>{{ $message }}</strong>' +
                                            '</span>' +
                                        '@enderror' +
                                    '</div>' + ...

I want to use old function like the code above but I can't use it. I don't know why it is not working but I assume that it is because of the different of how Blade and JavaScript read the code in different side. However, I need to use the old function.
The key is that I know I need to change this line of code : 'value="{{ old('reward.' + key + 'reward.owner_name', ) }}"' to add the default value to it using value.reward_owner_name but I don't really know the syntax to do it properly.

You haven't really explained what your problem is.  Blade files runs on the server under PHP and generates the HTML/CSS/Javascript that is sent to the client (i.e. the browser). It would be a good idea to read [mre]. The three dots at the end of your code makes me think that there is more code in this blade view.

@PeterJames Yes, there is more code for the information of the reward. The key problem is that I know I need to change this line of code : 'value="{{ old('reward.' + key + 'reward.owner_name', ) }}"' to add the default value to it using value.reward_owner_name but I don't really know the syntax to do it properly.

Which line of code are you referring to?
Why is there a dot between reward and owner_name in reward.owner_name when just below you have _reward_owner_name?

@PeterJames I just edited my code. It is in the input type="text" tag where I set the value to be 'value="{{ old('reward.' + key + '.reward_owner_name', ) }}"' It is because I used id="reward_' + key + '_reward_owner_name_th" name="reward[' + key + '][reward_owner_name_th]" of the input like this so the data sent to the controller is in the mentioned structure.

Where do you define your reward object? reward.owner_name means that you are referring to the owner_name property of the reward object. I cannot see a reward object here.

In the following lines 'value="{{ old(\'reward.' + key + '.reward_owner_name\', ) }}"' and 'onkeyup="typeOnlyEN(\'reward_' + key + '_reward_owner_name\');" ' you have dots before and after key in the first line and underscores in the second line. Why are they different?

Sorry for my mistake. I got something wrong in the code. I get the data of reward information from this line of code : const reward_details = @json(old('reward'));

The reason of the differences are that the name I set for the input is different and the structure of the reward information is in something like array or json. When I sent the form, the data are sent with their names so the structure will be as shown.

Please do not share contact details on [so].

You are using code @error("reward.' + key + '.reward_type_id") but key here is from javascript's Object.entries(reward_details).forEach(([key, value]) right?

if so, then you cannot use key here since @error is rendered from php to your frontend and does not recognize key

you seem to confuse when php renders html and when javascript runs. In your code @error("reward.' + key + 'reward.reward_owner_name") implies there is a key PHP constant being used here, since at the point of html rendering, no js has been compiled

Btw, why are you loading old data from javscript? Did you execute post request via ajax? old data is returned from form post request

@AkirahA. are you posting via ajax?

@krisgjika I'm not posing via ajax. I'm using a simple form to do the add and remove items and then submit the form with the button not the ajax post.

First of all I think you are over complicating this, by not submitting the form via ajax (since you re-render rewards on error). By using a regular form submit, your page reloads on validation errors and you lose the current state of the form, for example: how many items have been created via addMoreItem.
So what if you didn't have to reload on validation errors?
$(document).ready(function () { // assuming you are using Jquery
  let form = $(`form#form-id`);
  form.submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    form.find(`.text-danger.error-msg`).remove(); // remove any previous messages
    form.find(`button[type="submit"]`).css({"cursor": 'not-allowed'}).prop('disabled', true); // disable submit until done

    $.ajax({
      type: form.attr('method'),
      url: form.attr('action'),
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        location.reload();
        // or window.location.replace(`{{ route('route-to-redirect-on-success') }}`)
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        if (xhr.status == 422) { // validation error
          Object.keys(xhr.responseJSON.errors).forEach((f) => {
            let error = xhr.responseJSON.errors[f][0]; // get first error message of field
            let input = form.find(`[name="${f}"]`); // find input matching name
            
            if (input.length == 0 && f.includes('.')) { // match fields such as parent.child => parent[child]
              let name = f.split('.').map((p, i) => {return i == 0 ? p : `[${p}]`}).join('');
              input = form.find(`[name="${name}"]`);
            }

            if (input.length) {
              input.parent().append(`<span class="text-danger error-msg">${error}</span>`); // append error to input container, assuming each input is contained in some other element like div, or change the selector for your need
            }
        }  else {
          alert(`Something went wrong!`);
        }

        form.find(`button[type="submit"]`).css({"cursor": ''}).prop('disabled', false); // re enable submit
      });
      
      return false;
  });
});


Thank you for your ideas on this. I'll try to follow your approach and give you feedback as soon as possible.

I'm not the expert on using AJAX but I have tried AJAX to send the data from the form in Blade file with this code :
let form = $('#form');
            
form.submit(function (e){
  e.preventDefault();

  // Send Data using AJAX
  $.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    type: form.attr('method'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    error: function(data){

      let status = data.status;
      console.log("Status : " + status);

      // Get Message
      let message = data.message;

      // alert("Message : " + message);

      // Show Alert Message
      Swal.fire({
        position: 'center',
        icon: 'error',
        title: message,
        showCloseButton: false,
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 2000
      })

      // Get All Error(s)
      let errors = data.all_errors;

      // Show Each Error
      // For Achievement + Reward Information
      $.each(errors, function(key, message){

        // Replace '.' from Reward Information Field(s)
        let elementID = key.replace(/\./g, '_');
        let element = $('#' + elementID);

        // Add 'is-invalid' Class
        element.addClass('is-invalid');

        // Append Error Message After Element
        element.after('<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert"><strong>' + message[0] + '</strong></span>');
      });

      // Get All Old Value(s)
      let old_values = data.old_values;
                        
      // Re-populate Form Fields with Old Value(s)
      // For Achievement
      $('#achievement_name_th').val(old_values.achievement_name_th);
      $('#achievement_name_en').val(old_values.achievement_name_en);
      $('#start_achievement_date').val(old_values.start_achievement_date);
      $('#finish_achievement_date').val(old_values.finish_achievement_date);
      $('#start_achievement_education_level_id').val(old_values.start_achievement_education_level_id).change();
      $('#start_achievement_academic_year').val(old_values.start_achievement_academic_year);
      $('#start_achievement_academic_semester').val(old_values.start_achievement_academic_semester);
      $('#finish_achievement_education_level_id').val(old_values.finish_achievement_education_level_id).change();
      $('#finish_achievement_academic_year').val(old_values.finish_achievement_academic_year);
      $('#finish_achievement_academic_semester').val(old_values.finish_achievement_academic_semester);
      
      // For Reward Total Items 
      $('#reward_total_items').val(old_values.reward_total_items);

      // Re-populate Form Fields with Old Value(s)
      // For Reward Information
      $.each(old_values.reward, function(key, value){
        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_award_status').val(value.reward_award_status);
        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_type_id').val(value.reward_type_id).change();
        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_owner_name_th').val(value.reward_owner_name_th);
        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_owner_name_en').val(value.reward_owner_name_en);
        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_owner_description_th').val(value.reward_owner_description_th);
        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_owner_description_en').val(value.reward_owner_description_en);
        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_date').val(value.reward_date);
        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_name_th').val(value.reward_name_th);
        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_name_en').val(value.reward_name_en);
        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_education_level_id').val(old_values.reward_education_level_id).change();
        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_academic_year').val(old_values.reward_academic_year);
        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_academic_semester').val(old_values.reward_academic_semester);
        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_prize_amount').val(old_values.reward_prize_amount);
        $('#' + 'reward' + '_' + key + '_' + 'reward_currency_id').val(old_values.reward_currency_id).change();
      });
    },
    success: function(response){
                    
      // Go to Student Profile Page
      window.location.replace(response.route);
    }
  });
});

After the validation failed, I used this code to send the old data I want to display with their error messages and the message for SweetAlert Pop-up. However, what is returned is in json and I cannot get back to the form which I don't really know why. This way get me the data I want but cannot take to where I want the data should be displayed which is very weird for me.
This is not the best solution, but I think sending data with AJAX is working better than the code I used earlier. Thank you to @kris gjika for this idea. For now, I have to figure out why I can't get back to the form.
If anyone has any ideas, please post yours in the comment below.
For more information, this is the code I used after the validation failed in the Controller :
if ($validator->fails()) {

  $data = array();

  $old_values = $request->all();
  $all_errors = $validator->errors();
  $message = 'ขออภัย!\nกรุณากรอกข้อมูลให้ถูกต้องและครบถ้วน!';

  $data = compact(
    'message',
    'old_values',
    'all_errors',
  );

  return $data; 
}

This is the form tag I used and the route I set :
<form id="form" name="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('achievement_info.store_achievement_info', ['profile_id' => $student->id]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    Route::post('/menu_student/{profile_id}/store_achievement_info', [AchievementInfoController::class, 'store'])->middleware('auth')->name('achievement_info.store_achievement_info');

